# Concatenate a string on map function javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an object **lengthOfStay** in which I'm trying to concatenate the values inside it and put it on **customerApplication.lengthOfStay**

```
lengthOfStay:{
    yrs: '',
    mos:''
},
customerApplication: {
    length_of_stay: this.lengthOfStayYrsMos
}

computed: {
     lengthOfStayYrsMos(){
        return this.customerApplication.length_of_stay = 
        Object.keys(this.lengthOfStay).map(k =>  this.lengthOfStay[k]).join(" ")
      }
}
```

so for the concatenation looks good and the result for example is

```
lengthOfStay:{
    yrs: '2',
    mos:'2'
},
//result
customerApplication: {
    length_of_stay: "2 2"
}
```

how can I concatenate a string on it ? so that the result would be

```
customerApplication: {
    length_of_stay: "2 Yrs. & 2 Mos."
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```js
Object.keys(this.lengthOfStay).map(k =>  {
   return `${this.lengthOfStay[k]} ${k}.` 
}).join(" & ")
```

**FOR FIRST KEY UPPERCASE**

```js
Object.keys(this.lengthOfStay).map(k =>  {
   return `${this.lengthOfStay[k]} ${k.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + k.slice(1)}.` 
}).join(" & ")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.entries()` to get both key and value from object, then change first character to uppercase and concatenate in desired format

```js
let data ={ lengthOfStay:{ yrs: '2', mos:'2' }}
let capFirstChar = (str)=> str[0].toUpperCase() + str.substr(1,)

let op = Object.entries(data.lengthOfStay)
               .map(([key, value]) => `${value} ${capFirstChar(key)}.`)
               .join(' & ')

console.log(op)
```